# Unable to use tar to run an archive through bzip2 compression

Tags: tar, compression

I am having difficulty compression an archive with bzip using tar. 
The archive I have is user-logs.tar.

I am attempting to run this:

```
tar -jf user-logs.tar
```

I get this error:

```
tar: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label'  options
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

I also attempted using -c to create a new file with the bzip filename extension with no luck.

```
# tar -cvjf user-logs.tar.gz user-logs.tar
user-logs.tar
tar (child): bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: To compress `user-logs.tar`, do `bzip -9 user-logs.tar`. To package and compress `tar jcf user-logs.tar.bz2 file file file...`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error message tells what to do: you probably need to add `-c` (for *create*), e.g.,

```
tar -jcf user-logs.tar  myargs
```

as well as some arguments *myargs* (things to put into the `user-logs.tar` archive).

In the second case, the problem is that you do not have `bzip2` installed.  The tar program relies upon this *external* program to do compression.

If you have a tar archive and simply want to compress it, you could do this:

```
bzip2 user-logs.tar
```

which (if you *had* `bzip2` installed) would change the file to `user-logs.tar.bz2` (and usually make it much smaller).

For installing `bzip2`, it depends on the system you are using.  For example, with Ubuntu that would be

```
sudo apt-get install bzip2
```

while Fedora might be (perhaps `dnf`):

```
sudo yum install bzip2
```

The GNU `tar` program does not know how to compress an existing file such as `user-logs.tar` (`bzip2` does that).  The `tar` program can use external compression programs `gzip`, `bzip2`, `xz` by opening a *pipe* to those programs, sending a tar archive via the pipe to the compression utility, which compresses the data which it reads from `tar` and writes the result to the filename which the `tar` program specifies.

Alternatively, the `tar` and compression utility *could* be the same program.  BSD tar does its compression using `libarchive` (they're not really distinct except in name).

Further reading:

- [3.2. Using bzip2 with tar](http://www.bzip.org/bzip2-howto/with-tar.html)
- [Compression support](http://invisible-island.net/autoconf/portability-tar.html#comp_compression)

Comment: I didnt know it relied on the external bzip thank you. But, what If i dont want to add anything to the archive. I  just want to compress the archive that already exists with bzip2

Comment: For *that*, you need the external `bzip2` program.

Comment: I think my confusion was this, tell me if this is correct, once a archive (file.tar) is created, you cant compress it with the tar utility. Tar will compress and archive at the same time. Is that right?

Answer (score 5):

Error message `bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory` tells you that tar can't find bzip2. Most likely you don't have it installed.

Install it via `yum install bzip2` or `apt-get install bzip2` or something like that, depending on your OS.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I interpret your question and data correctly, but it looks to me as if you already have the tar ball and just want it compressed?

```
bzip2 user-logs.tar
```

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: @Oscalation :  OK, so my "solution" above is correct. Next time just create your tarball w/ the appropriate switch:  **tar cvzf user-logs.tbz2 /path/to/logs**

Comment: @tink: the `z` option is for compressing with gzip; you probably wanted to say `j` for the bzip2 compression

Comment: @FrancescoTurco: that's correct.